# Compare two different objects in different lists in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java-8

I need to check if an object present in list A exists in list B without using nested for loops because if the lists have a large size, it takes too much time.

This is my code :

```
for(Person el : persons)
{
    for(Client in : clients)
    {
        if(el.getIdentifier() == in.getTire().getIdentifier())
        {
            exists=true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i achieve the same result without using loops and break?

Comment: Any object or do you know which object you want to search? From your code it seems to be any object, but just to be sure.

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this without using loops and break ?

Comment: You will need to loop through both lists one way or another, but the loops don't have to be nested though.

Comment: What i'm asking for is to get the same result using another method like anyMatch, sorry about the wrong tag and no it's not homework , i'm trying to optimize the code.

Comment: @JoãoDias i'm just checking if the client in list B has the same identitifer as a person in list B

Comment: @MauricePerry you should undelete your answer

Comment: What exactly is the data type of your ID field? I might do some performance testing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the complexity of your code from O(NxM) to O(N+M):

```
    Set<Integer> personIds = persons.stream()
            .map(e -> e.getIdentifier())
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    boolean exists = clients.stream().anyMatch(
            c -> personIds.contains(c.getTire().getIdentifier()));
```

Comment: Good Answer. The Question mentions a large number of objects. I wonder if using a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) instead of `HashSet` might give better performance.

Comment: @BasilBourque I doubt it: the access time for a skiplist is in O(log(n)) instead of O(1) for a hash table.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do it like this

```
Set<String> identifierSet = new HashSet<>();

for (Person el : persons) {
    identifierSet.add(el.getIdentifier());
}

for (Client in : clients) {
    if (identifierSet.contains(in.getTire().getIdentifier())) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of the for loops and use anyMatch or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve performance by using data structures better suited for fast lookups. If you store clients in a HashMap where the key is the identifier, and the value is the client object then your code becomes:

```
for(Person el : persons)
{
    if (clients.containsKey(el.getIdentifier()) {
      exists=true;
    }
}
```

Now you only have one loop, and the cost of looking up in the hashmap is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

As `anyMatch` is mentioned, the following solution based on Stream API can be offered (assuming the type of identifiers is `String`):

```java
// prepare set of identifiers in clients
Set<String> clientIds = clients
    .stream()                                // Stream<Client>
    .map(in -> in.getTire().getIdentifier()) // Stream<String> client ids
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

boolean anyPersonIsClient = persons
   .stream()                    // Stream<Person>
   .map(Person::getIdentifier)  // Stream<String> person identifiers
   .anyMatch(clientIds::contains);

boolean allPersonsAreClient = persons
   .stream()                    // Stream<Person>
   .map(Person::getIdentifier)  // Stream<String> identifiers
   .allMatch(clientIds::contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a classical :

```
contains(Object o) //Returns true if this list contains the specified element.
```

So you could just do loop instead :

```
for(Person el : persons)
{

        if(clients.contains(el.getIdentifier()))
        {
            exists=true;
            break;
        }        
}
```

But looking at your code, and depending on what you're aiming for, you could use:

```
containsAll(Collection c)
       //   Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.
```